# Going back to paginated results from individual page in jekyll

Tags: pagination, jekyll

I'm wondering if there's a way to go back to paginated posts from an individual post in Jekyll.

I right now, I have it redirect back to the homepage from an individual post, but I would like to somehow have it navigate back to the paginated results that the user first clicked the article on.

My code is on github, the master branch should show it. Here's a link to the actual pagination stuff (taken directly from jekyll's website).  https://github.com/vernak2539/babble.byvernacchia

I've searched Jekyll's website and cannot seem to find anything.

**edit:** solution marked as correct only applies to navigating directly to page from paginated results, not going from a third party to a specific page (don't know why i wanted to do that in the first place).

Comment: Same question here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage that by sending to your post page the url of the pagination, for example :

```
myblog.com/my_post.html?url=page3
```

And then in the post page, you retrieve the value passed in the parameter `url` to go back to it.

Comment: but then that only works if i go to that page navigating from the pagination, and it won't work if I navigate to it from a search result or direct navigation. Or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: Indeed... Sorry... It only works when you come from the paginated page. But do you really need to go back to the paginated page if you don't come from one? If yes, this is no solution. But if no, may be you can hide the 'back to pagination page' if the parameter is empty. This way when you can from a paginated page, you can go back to it, and if come from any other link in your site, you hide the 'back to paginated page' link.

Comment: that's actually a pretty good thought. I guess i really don't care what paginated page to go back to if they've come directly to the page. Thanks